# When does Jade say that just sub the speed of light is the fastest the ship can go?

Tags: quotes, homestuck

When John and Jade were going through the Yellow Yard, John asks if they could go any faster to which Jade replies that the fastest the ship can go is just sub the speed of light. When does she say this?

Comment: Haven't you just answered your own question?

Comment: @OrangeDog - Maybe Cyberson is looking for a link to the page where this is said?

Comment: Just "sub" the speed of light? Really? I take it that English is not the first language of the guy who writes *Homestuck*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for a link, it looks like Jade and John go through the Yellow Yard in [Act 6 Intermission 1](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=006195), Jade first mentions the Yellow Yard to John [here](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=006198), then [here](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=006203) Jade says:

> JADE: im just trying to estimate our arrival time
>
> JADE: based on our current velocity, which is about as close to light speed as i can make it go

Then in the [next one](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=006204) (what do you call these things? panels? screens) Jade gives more of an explanation, which I mostly can't follow because I haven't read Homestuck, but it includes the following line:

> JADE: and once we leave the suns domain, our travel is limited by the speed of light, like everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

When John and Jade were going through the Yellow Yard, and John asked if they could go any faster.